# Is there a set of reasonable default Type Filters for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, types

For each new workspace, it is time consuming in Eclipse to configure amongst other settings the type filters.

Is there a reasonable default set of filters that avoids in most setups that hardly ever called classes called "Map" or "List" are being suggested when 99,9% of all cases java.util.Map and List is desired?

Answer (score 3):

There is unfortunately as of now no option to import type filters from a file. An import can only be achieved by editing the line starting with

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.typefilter.enabled
```

in the file

```
<Workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs.
```

My suggestion for a reasonable default, attempting to cover as many notorious punk classes as possible:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.typefilter.enabled=antlr.*;com.*.Iterator;com.*.Map;com.*.Set;com.ibm.wsspi.*;com.ibm.xml.xlxp.*;com.lowagie.text.*;com.*.List;com.sun.awt.*;com.sun.istack.*;com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.*;com.sun.media.*;com.sun.xml.internal.*;java.awt.*;javassist.bytecode.*;javax.swing.*;net.sf.cglib.asm.*;org.*.List;org.*.Map;org.*.Set;org.apache.commons.lang.*;org.hibernate.mapping.List;sun.org.mozilla.*;
```

Please send me more suggestions and I will try to update this answers from time to time.

Comment: `There is unfortunately as of now no option to import type filters from a file` File -> Import/Export, General -> Preferences takes care of type filters among other things.

Comment: (At least in Eclipse Neon.)